# Use existing languages in BNF with TinyPG?

Tags: regex, bnf, ebnf, compiler-compiler, tinypg

How can I use [these BNF grammars](http://www.devincook.com/GOLDParser/grammars/index.htm) which are in [GOLD meta-syntax](http://www.devincook.com/GOLDParser/doc/meta-language/index.htm) (RegExp + BNF) with TinyPG? I'm new to BNF so approximately what sort of conversion will I have to do to convert BNF to EBNF?

I believe it should be pretty simple since TinyPG needs RegExp + **EBNF** in comparison to the GOLD grammars which are RegExp + **BNF**.

Also, is there any TinyPG source code for any language available, just to see what sort of conversion I would have to do?

Comment: What is TinyPG? Is it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/TinyPG.aspx?

Answer (score 1):

EBNF is not *entirely* backwards compatible with BNF, however the differences are actually slight, you should be familiar with the document at

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/misc/ebnf.pdf

Primarily you have to handle the special characters <>|:=  (enclosed in double quotes).

You could just use the GOLD meta-syntax engine to output your parser if it can be in one of the supported languages - instead of using TinyPG...

It begs the question - What language will your parser be in when you are implementing it?